# Why my java web is like flickered every time it loads a page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, spring

www.mypersonalprojects.net, username: tempuser, password: tempuser

Above are my java web app address and it's username & password.
My question is, why does it like flicker every time it loads a page?

Below is the code of the login page. Other pages are about the same, just a bit different on the main body content only. Is there something wrong with the code? Or CSS? Or is it because of the java web hoster i'm using(mochahost)?To all java/spring/html/web masters out there, please tell me what is the problem?

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <title>Login Page</title>
 <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent Pro' rel='stylesheet'>
 <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/main.css">
</head>

<body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>

 <header>
  <div id="logo-container">
   <a id="logo1"  href="http://www.ghhs.com.my"><img alt="GHHS" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/ghhs_logo.png"></a>
   <h1 id="logo2"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">OPC LEAD CAPTURER</a></h1>
  </div>
 </header>

 <div id="big-wrapper">

  <div id="login-form-wrapper">
 
   <h3 class="page-title" id="login-head">Welcome</h3>
  
   <form name='f' action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login'
    method='POST'>
  
    <table class="login-form-table">

     <tr>
      <td><input class="login-field" type='text' name='username' placeholder="Username"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input class="login-field" type='password' name='password' placeholder="Password" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>
       <input class="login-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
      </td>
     </tr>
     
    </table>
  
    <c:if test="${param.error!=null}"> 
     <p class="error" id="login-error" >Incorrect username or password</p>
    </c:if>
  
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
     value="${_csrf.token}" />
  
   </form>
   
   <c:if test="${param.loggedout==true}">
    <p class="action-message" id="action-message">You've successfully logged out</p> 
   </c:if>
  
  </div>
 
 </div>
 
 <footer>
  <p>Copyright &#169; <a href="http://www.ghhs.com.my">Golden Horse Health Sanctuary</a></p>
 </footer>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  function closeDiv()
  {
   var actionMessage = document.getElementById("action-message");
   var loginError = document.getElementById("login-error");
   
   if(actionMessage != null)
   {
    actionMessage.style.display = "none";
   }
   
   if(loginError != null)
   {
    loginError.style.display = "none";
   }
  }
  
  window.setTimeout(closeDiv, 3000);
 
 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when the page is loading, it takes some time for rendering, this also depend on yor bandwidth..for example the background image will take sometime to reload before being rendered..so you may see some flickering there....is this your issue?

Comment: Try preloading the background image. Preload will stop the page load until the image is fully loaded. See if that solves the flickering:   <link rel="preload" as="image" href="background1.png">